# Splash screen flashing before homepage

Tags: javascript, splash-screen

I implemented a simple splash screen in my website that shows once per session before revealing the homepage.

It works fine but the problem comes when you reload the page and the splash screen is not supposed to show anymore but only the homepage. The splash screen "flashes/blinks" for 0.5 seconds like the function is loading after the rest of the content.

If instead of using `$("#intro").hide();` right after the document is ready I implement in via CSS, the effect is the opposite. The homepage appears 0.5

Is there a way to achieve this in a better way? I know there's a similar question regarding that but didn't show a clear answer.

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#intro").hide();
    if(localStorage.getItem('IntroTime') != 'shown'){
        $("#intro").show();
        localStorage.setItem('IntroTime','shown')
    }

    // Close on click
    $('#intro').click(function(e)  {
    $('#intro').fadeOut();
    });

    // Also close after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#intro').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: Did you try to set style="display:none" on input element.

Comment: Yes. If instead of using $("#intro").hide(); right after the document is ready I implement in via CSS (display:none), the effect is the opposite. The homepage appears 0.5

Comment: look at this example,Not visible for 0.5 seconds..  https://jsfiddle.net/tp89xyfd/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can it be that I'm working on Wordpress? It might be a problem with prioritising the scripts or something like that?

Comment: Document.Ready() works after dom ready. So it is normal to seeing element in a short time before hide code run.

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve it then?